# How to write a function returning Chebyshev Polynominals of the first kind using Nest[]?

Tags: pure-function, iteration

I want to create a function returning the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind using the in build Nest[] function, preferably with a pure function.

I know there exist an in-build function for the Chebyshev polynomials yet for the matter of an exercise I would like to write a function myself using Nest[]

[image: definition of function]

I managed to get the same problem working with a do function as

[image]

All my attempts so far have been uncussesful. Any help appreciated.

Gordon

Comment: Can you show us your attempts so far? Often it’s just a simple fix you need, and that way we don’t have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MarcoB I have added a successful implementation of mine using the Do[] function. I struggle to translate it into the pure function really.

Comment: If the linked question does not suit your needs, edit this question to explain why.

Comment: @Gordon Also take a look at the answer I posted below. For future reference, please post code as text, rather than as an image, so people can copy it and paste it in their MMA to try it out.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you yes it actually help. Saw that question before, yet misunderstood it then. Will postcode in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[chebT]
chebT[0, _] = 1;
chebT[n_Integer, x_] := 
   First@ 
     Nest[
      Apply[{Expand[2x #1 - #2], #1}&],
      {x, 1}, 
      n - 1
     ]

chebT[3, x] == ChebyshevT[3, x]
(* True *)
```